# submit a number then transfer to a certain page depending on your answer

Tags: javascript, html, button, input, onclick

So I am trying to code this responding web page depending on the value you enter, but it isn't working!

Here is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>chose</title>

<body>
  <div>
    <input type="number" id="userInput" />
    <script>
      var xa = document.getElementById("userInput").value;

      function goTo(xa) {
        if (xa == 1) {
          window.location.replace = 'first Page.html';
        } else if (xa == 2) {
          window.location.replace = 'second Page.html';
        } else if (xa == 3) {
          window.location.replace = 'Third Page.html';
        }
    </script>
    <button onclick="goTo(xa)">Next</button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

the fix thanks
the problem was with the replace and the var had to get in the function

```
    <div>
      <input type="number" id="userInput" />
      <script>    
        function goTo() {
          var xa = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
          if(xa == 1) {
            window.location.href='1stPage.html';
          } else if(xa == 2) {
            window.location.href='2ndPage.html';
          } else if(xa == 3) {
            window.location.href='3rdPage.html';
          } else {
            window.location.href='FailPage.html'
          }
        }
      </script>
      <button onclick="goTo()">Next</button>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it is not working?"
I can see a problem, and it is that xa will have always null value. You should capture it inside the goto function:
function goTo() {
var xa = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
// rest of your code
}

Comment: 1) you don't need an argument to goTo function ... 2) you need to read the value of the input **inside** the goTo function

Comment: also your function is borken ... hence the `"SyntaxError: missing } after function body"` you see in the browser console when you tried debugging your code ... I *assume* you have at least tried to *debug* your code of course

Comment: Your code doesn't work because it has syntax errors. You missed the closing `}` after the function body.